# Restarting build without cleaning

Tags: python, pyside, setuptools

I'm building a Python extension module with setuptools. When I do

```
setup.py bdist_egg
```

all files generated during any previous build are first deleted and the module is rebuilt from scratch. Is it possible to restart the build *without* first deleting the files generated during a previous build?

**Note**: Someone is going to ask, why do you want to do that? Here is why. I'm building PySide from sources on Windows. It is a large and complex build where setuptools calls CMake which calls qmake which generates makefiles which are then executed by Visual C++. The whole thing takes about 20 minutes.

Often the build fails with errors such as:

`mt.exe : general error c101008d: Failed to write the updated manifest to the resource of file "shiboken.exe". The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

This happens because the file is momentarily locked by my anti-virus software. I have had this problem before. The solution was to simply restart the build without cleaning. But then I did not build with setuptools. How do I do that with setuptools?

Comment: I think you need customize your own build use like ant build.

Comment: +1, sounds like you should split your build process into two parts, so you can build your C++ artifacts first, and then build your Python artifacts separately (and more quickly).  Presumably, the Python build doesn't depend on the C++ source itself (probably headers only)?